# How to stop create if a parameter value is empty/missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to create an event with some nested params, but I want to return a 400 if certain parameters are empty.  Is there some built in way to do this without checking `params` and returning early?

for exmaple:

```
event = Event.create! params.require(:event).permit(
      :name,
      :owner_id,
      attachments: [],
      location_attributes: [
        :custom,
        :building,
        :street_1,
        :street_2,
        :city,
        :state,
        :postal,
        :country,
        :latitude,
        :longitude,
      ],
    )
```

Let's say I want to reject if `latitude` and `longitude` are empty - what's the best way to do that?

Comment: Pls try without strong parameter like this params.(:name,owner_id,etc......)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `require` on your desired attributes too, but it's a bit tricky. Check the last example here https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require

In your case it would be something like:

```
params.require(:event).permit(
  :name,
  :owner_id,
  attachments: [],
  location_attributes: [
    :custom,
    :building,
    :street_1,
    :street_2,
    :city,
    :state,
    :postal,
    :country,
    :latitude,
    :longitude,
  ],
).tap do |event_params|
  event_params[:location_attributes].require(:latitude, :longitude)
end
```

I'm not sure if that's the final syntax since the doc example does not have nested attributes, but I hope it points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

While you can just call `require` several times:

```
def event_params
  params.require(:event).require(:location_attributes).tap do |p|
    p.require(:latitude)
    p.require(:longitude)
  end
  # ...
  params.require(:event).permit(
      :name,
      :owner_id,
      attachments: [],
      location_attributes: [
        :custom,
        :building,
        :street_1,
        :street_2,
        :city,
        :state,
        :postal,
        :country,
        :latitude,
        :longitude,
      ]
    )
end
```

This really bloats your controller.

And I think you are really just overcomplicating something that should be handled by using the non-bang persistence methods (the ones that don't raise an error and that don't end with !) and validations on the model layer. Exceptions should not be used for the normal controller flow.

The bang methods such as `create!` should only really be used in a non-interactive context (such as seed files) or when you are using a transaction and need to rollback the transaction on failure.

So you use can use `.require` to bail early if the params are completely unusable but for the more "normal" case where a one the attributes is missing or blank should be handled by validations.

This lets you actually provide feedback to the user/client about what is missing and the 422 response is actually more appropriate.

```
def create
   @event.new(event_params)
   if @event.save
     respond_to do |f|
       f.html { redirect_to @event }
       f.json { status :created, location: @event }
     end
   else
     respond_to do |f|
       f.html { render :new}
       f.json { status :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
end
```

---

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :locations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations
  validates_associated :locations
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  validates_presence_of :latitude, :longitude
end
```